# How do I get the last character, then last two so on.. of a string?

Tags: java

I am a beginner in java, I need jour help, I would like to print last character of a string, then last two.. so on.

Many thanks for your time and help.
(I don't need video tutorials advice etc.)

```
String vacantion = "Vacantion";

int number = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < vacantion.length(); i++) 
{
    System.out.println(vacantion.charAt(vacantion.length() - number));

    number++;
}

// The output should look like this //
// n,
// on,
// ion,
// tion,

// so on.
```

Comment: `I don't need video tutorials advice` - yes, I think you do. We are not here to write the code for you. You need to do the reading on your own. I would suggest you start by reading the "String" API. You can use the "substring(...)" method to access parts of the string.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What has or hasn't worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace the charAt method with the substring method:

```
String vacantion = "Vacantion";

int number = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < vacantion.length(); i++)
{
    System.out.println(vacantion.substring(vacantion.length() - number));

    number++;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To get the characters of any string, you would use String.substring(firstIndex, lastIndex) or String.charAt(index).

String.substring(firstIndex, lastIndex) would give you the letters between firstIndex and lastIndex (including first, excluding last) whereas charAt(index) would return you the char at that index in your String (note that charAt() will always and only return 1 char).

For example:

```
String sample = "Hello World";

// substring() examples
System.out.println(sample.substring(0,5); // This would give you an output of "Hello"

System.out.println(sample.substring(6, sample.length()); // This would give you "World"

// charAt() examples
System.out.println(sample.charAt(4)); // This would return 'o'

System.out.println(sample.charAt(str.length() - 1); // This would give you 'd'
```

Hope this helps!